# Anisotropy of quasar distribution

Tags: quasars, resource-request

In a paper titled

> Arp, H. (1984). Distribution of quasars on the sky. Journal of Astrophysics and Astronomy,
>   5(1):31-41.

at [Journal of Astrophysics and Astronomy](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02714970), Halton Arp wrote that there is a notable clustering of quasars at $21^h<RA<3^h$, and a marked lack of quasars at $9^h<RA<15^h$, but I haven't been able to find other references to the same distribution. The paper was published in 1984, so has anyone else published a similar result, or has this observation been

- refuted, or
- explained?